# Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null error with plain javascript

Tags: javascript

I am creating new element by javascript and appending it to already existing div:

```
function addElement(){
    var dodato = document.getElementById('dodato');
    var input = document.getElementById('input');
    if(input.value!==""){
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        dodato.appendChild(div);
        var ele = dodato.lastChild;
        ele.style.width = "200px";
        ele.style.float = "left";
        ele.innerHTML = input.value;
        ele.id = input.value;
        var deletE = document.createElement('span');
        ele.appendChild(deletE);
        var deletEe = ele.lastChild;
        deletEe.innerHTML = 'X';
        deletEe.style.color = "red";
        deletEe.style.float = 'right';
        deletEe.setAttribute('onclick','deleteE('+input.value+')');
    }
}
```

`dodato` is div where I add all new elements and all of those elements have different `id`

By clicking on span I call new function to delete some added element with specific id.

```
function deleteE(delete_value){
    var dodato = document.getElementById('dodato');
    var el = document.getElementById(delete_value);
    dodato.removeChild(el);
}
```

The error I keep getting is:

Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

```
dodato.removeChild(el);
```

Comment: Why are you trying to get the parentNode of #dodato, when you're appending the requisite div as a child node of #dodato? Your delete function would be deleting #dodato's sibling node, rather than child node.

Comment: In fact, it should be as simple as dodato.removeChild(el)

Comment: @Snowmonkey  Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
    at deleteE (

Answer (score 1):

In your first code snippet, you say

```
deletEe.setAttribute('onclick','deleteE('+input.value+')');
```

And in `deleteE` you then say:

```
var el = document.getElementById(delete_value);
```

So you try to get an elementById with its *value*, not its *id*. Change

```
deletEe.setAttribute('onclick','deleteE('+input.value+')');
```

to

```
deletEe.setAttribute('onclick','deleteE('+input.id+')');
```